# How to render a checkbox in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable

This is my code to render a JTable and change the color of rows, but it doesn't show a checkbox in column 6, only string (true,false).

Can you provide a solution to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

```
    public class JLabelRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer
{
  private MyJTable myTable;
  /**
   * Creates a Custom JLabel Cell Renderer
   * @param t your JTable implmentation that holds the Hashtable to inquire for
   * rows and colors to paint.
   */
  public JLabelRenderer(MyJTable t)
  {
    this.myTable = t;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the component used for drawing the cell.  This method is
   * used to configure the renderer appropriately before drawing.
   * see TableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(...); for more comments on the method
   */
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
  {
    setOpaque(true); //JLabel isn't opaque by default

    setText(value.toString());
    setFont(myTable.getFont());

    if(!isSelected)//if the row is not selected then use the custom color
    setBackground(myTable.getRowToPaint(row));
    else //if the row is selected use the default selection color
    setBackground(myTable.getSelectionBackground());

    //Foreground could be changed using another Hashtable...
    setForeground(myTable.getForeground());

    // Since the renderer is a component, return itself
    return this;
  }

  // The following methods override the defaults for performance reasons
  public void validate() {}
  public void revalidate() {}
  protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {}
  public void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, boolean oldValue, boolean newValue) {}
}
```

This is the table:

```
import javax.swing.JTable;    
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.awt.Color;

public class MyJTable extends JTable
{
  Hashtable rowsToPaint = new Hashtable(1);

  /**
   * Default Constructor
   */
  public MyJTable()
  {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Set the TableModel and then render each column with a custom cell renderer
   * @param tm TableModel
   */
  public void setModel(TableModel tm)
  {
    super.setModel(tm);
    renderColumns(new JLabelRenderer(this));
  }

  /**
   * Add a new entry indicating:
   * @param row the row to paint - the first row = 0;
   * @param bgColor background color
   */
  public void addRowToPaint(int row, Color bgColor)
  {
    rowsToPaint.put(new Integer(row), bgColor);
    this.repaint();// you need to repaint the table for each you put in the hashtable.
  }

  /**
   * Returns the user selected BG Color or default BG Color.
   * @param row the row to paint
   * @return Color BG Color selected by the user for the row
   */
  public Color getRowToPaint(int row)
  {
    Color bgColor = (Color)rowsToPaint.get(new Integer(row));
    return (bgColor != null)?bgColor:getBackground();
  }

  /**
   * Render all columns with the specified cell renderer
   * @param cellRender TableCellRenderer
   */
  public  void renderColumns(TableCellRenderer cellRender)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<this.getModel().getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
      renderColumn(this.getColumnModel().getColumn(i), cellRender);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Render a TableColumn with the sepecified Cell Renderer
   * @param col TableColumn
   * @param cellRender TableCellRenderer
   */
  public void renderColumn(TableColumn col, TableCellRenderer cellRender)
  {
    try{
          col.setCellRenderer(cellRender);
        }catch(Exception e){System.err.println("Error rendering column: [HeaderValue]: "+col.getHeaderValue().toString()+" [Identifier]: "+col.getIdentifier().toString());}
  }
}
```

here is my screen
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you probably know, JTable will render boolean values as checkboxes for you.  I suppose that your problem is that, out of the box, you cannot set custom background color per row based on specific criteria in your data. You can create a new `TableCellRenderer` for your `boolean` column.

You have a couple options:

1. you can put a test in your current renderer to determine whether the `value` passed in is boolean or not, and if so, configure a `JCheckbox` instance to be returned.  This could effect what you want, but you would need to be careful, as your renderer is called often and if you create one-off `JCheckbox`es, it could cause a lot of churn.
2. alternatively, you could create a new `TableCellRenderer` that extends `JCheckbox` (just as your current one extends `JLabel`.  You would want to refactor your current coloring logic such that it could be shared between the two renderers.  Finally, you would want to associate this renderer with your column. You can either do this by setting it as the default renderer on the table for a certain `Class` (`myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Class, TableCellRenderer)`), or setting it as the renderer for a specific column (`myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(int).setCellRenderer(TableCellRenderer)`)

Answer (score 7):

The best solution to this problem is to implement your own `TableModel` (typically by sub-classing `AbstractTableModel`) and implement the `getColumnClass(int)` method to return `Boolean.class` for the column you wish to render as a `JCheckBox`.

There is no need to implement your own `TableCellRenderer` as the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` used by `JTable` by default will automatically render `Boolean` columns as `JCheckbox`es.

Comment: incase you need the checkbox containing some ID for example. Then you need to use customEditor & Renderer, am I right? :D

Comment: I always follow this approach to render checkboxes.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks **akf** i solved it by :

add class :

```
public class CheckBoxRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {

          CheckBoxRenderer() {
            setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          }

          public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
              boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (isSelected) {
              setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
              //super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
              setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
              setForeground(table.getForeground());
              setBackground(table.getBackground());
            }
            setSelected((value != null && ((Boolean) value).booleanValue()));
            return this;
          }
}
```

Edit constructor of Mytable:

```
 public MyJTable(DefaultTableModel md)
  {
    super(md);
    CheckBoxRenderer checkBoxRenderer = new CheckBoxRenderer();
    this.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setCellRenderer(checkBoxRenderer);
  }
```

Comment: If the above code should not work, as in my case due to a look&feel that ignored opaque-ness of the JCheckbox (even when I set setOpaque(true) ), you can add the following:
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  g.setColor(getBackground());
  g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
  super.paint(g);
}

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to use the [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) approach for something like this. It will work without creating individual renderers for each column.