# CheckBox -- new Boolean(true/false)

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, boolean

Anyone can help me understand why this code doesnt show checkbox icon instead of text?
I have tried to find things on the internet about this, but didnt find anything :(

```
JTabbedPane tabProcessamentoSalarial = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
tabbedPane.addTab("Remunera\u00E7\u00F5es", null, tabProcessamentoSalarial, null);

JPanel pnlAcumulados = new JPanel();
tabProcessamentoSalarial.addTab("Acumulados", null, pnlAcumulados, null);
pnlAcumulados.setLayout(null);

String[] columnAcumulados = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
Object[][] dataAcumulados = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(true)}
};

JTable tblAcumulados = new JTable(dataAcumulados, columnAcumulados);

JScrollPane scrollPaneAcumulados = new JScrollPane(tblAcumulados);
tblAcumulados.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

tblAcumulados.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
scrollPaneAcumulados.setBounds(46, 36, 508, 160);
pnlAcumulados.add(scrollPaneAcumulados);
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the problem in the code? Just an advice , don't use `new Integer(10)` just put  `10` and in `new Boolean(true)` just use or `true` or `Boolean.TRUE` , and don't use `null` layout, swing was designed to use with Layout Managers

Comment: If i use just "true" this just show me...'true' instead of selected checkbox.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: true without " ", and don't use never `new Boolean(true)` use as i said  `Boolean.TRUE` instead.

Comment: I just have this: {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", 5, true}

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and we can better help sooner, make a correct example where we just have to copy paste, and we try it out!

Comment: The code is already there, just added a pic. Where it says: true. should show a checkbox selected.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're trying to follow the Oracle [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).

Unfortunately, the examples aren't very clear.

If you use a String and Object[] source, you will not get a check box.  You will get text, just like you found out.

You must use a TableModel for Swing to recognize boolean fields and display a check box.  The [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) works in most cases.

Here's Oracle's [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDemoProject/src/components/TableDemo.java).  I don't think it's very good, but I don't have an example handy.

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                    "Last Name",
                                    "Sport",
                                    "# of Years",
                                    "Vegetarian"};
    private Object[][] data = {
    {"Kathy", "Smith",
     "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
    {"John", "Doe",
     "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Sue", "Black",
     "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Jane", "White",
     "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Joe", "Brown",
     "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    /*
     * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
     * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
     * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
     * rather than a check box.
     */
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * editable.
     */
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
        //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
        if (col < 2) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * data can change.
     */
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                               + " to " + value
                               + " (an instance of "
                               + value.getClass() + ")");
        }

        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("New value of data:");
            printDebugData();
        }
    }

    private void printDebugData() {
        int numRows = getRowCount();
        int numCols = getColumnCount();

        for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As akf pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155428/1200914), just create a new class:

public class CheckBoxRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {

```
      CheckBoxRenderer() {
        setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      }

      public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
          boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
          setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
          //super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
          setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
          setForeground(table.getForeground());
          setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
        setSelected((value != null && ((Boolean) value).booleanValue()));
        return this;
      }
```

}

Then, after inserting the model to your table type:

```
CheckBoxRenderer checkBoxRenderer = new CheckBoxRenderer();
mytable.getColumnModel().getColumn(number_of_the_one_I_want).setCellRenderer(checkBoxRenderer);
```