# JCheckBox in JTable showing just True/False value

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I'd created a JTable and overrided the return types to show the JCheckBox in the first Cell, but instead I show true/false value. How can I see just the Box and not the value?

```
public JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"", "ID", "Cod. Proveedor", "Empresa", "Nombre", "Responsable", "F. Entrada", "H. Entrada", "F. Salida", "H. Salida", "Nº Tarjeta", "Tipo"}, 0))
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return Boolean.class;   
            case 1:
                return String.class;
            case 2:
                return String.class;
            case 3:
                return String.class;
            case 4:
                return String.class;
            case 5:
                return String.class;
            case 6:
                return String.class;
            case 7:
                return String.class;
            case 8:
                return String.class;
            case 9:
                return String.class;
            case 10:
                return String.class;
            case 11:
                return String.class;
            default:
                return String.class;
        }
    }
};
public JScrollPane sP = new JScrollPane(table);
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
model.addRow(new Object[]{false, result.getString("ID").trim(), result.getString("CODPROV").trim(), result.getString("EMPRESA").trim(), result.getString("NOMBRE").trim(), result.getString("RESPONS").trim(), fEntrada, hEntrada, fSalida, hSalida, result.getString("NTARJETA").trim(), result.getString("TIPO").trim(), false });
```

[image]

Comment: why did you pass boolean last value? your last value should be `String` check default case...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render a checkbox in a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154802/how-to-render-a-checkbox-in-a-jtable)

Comment: You code example works for me (after few adoptions), please create a **real** 
 [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You probably recreate the TableModel somewhere else in your code when you load the data into the model.

Answer (score 0):

In JTable if you want to add JCheckBox in a particular column of every row, you just need to columntype of that column to boolean and whenever you are adding any row to the table simply add true or false (boolean) value in that cell.

Refer below code snippet to set column datatype to boolean add checkbox.

```
Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] { Boolean.class, Object.class, Object.class, String.class, Object.class };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return columnTypes[columnIndex];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 JCheckBox check=new JCheckBox();

    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(check));
```

Try this code for check box

```
 String aa[]={"yellow","15","50"};
    JComboBox j2=new JComboBox(aa);

    j2.setEditable(true);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(j2));
```

if you wont use comboBox :)